How Can I Finish off this Proof on Axiom of Choice?
Question
Prove that the following is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice:
Every surjective map has a right inverse.
Attempt
I already showed that if the Axiom of Choice holds, then every surjective map has a right inverse.
Now, I want to show that if every surjective map has a right inverse, then the Axiom of Choice holds. Let’s say we have $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$. We want to choose an element from each $A_i$. Define $Y=\bigcup _{i\in I}A_i$ and consider the surjection $g:Y\rightarrow I$, where $g(y)=i$ if $y\in A_i$. By assumption, $g$ has a right inverse $f:I\rightarrow Y$ so that $g(f(i))=i$.
I need $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ to be mutually disjoint. However, I don’t seem to know how to make the argument that we have a family of mutually disjoint non-empty set.
Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Remember that you can always "disjointify" a given family of sets $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ by considering $$B_i=A_i\times\{i\}.$$ The family $(B_i)_{i\in I}$ is disjoint, but we can "translate nicely" between the $B_i$s and the $A_i$s to make a choice function for one family yield a choice function for the other.

In that case, is it correct to write the argument this way: Consider ${B_i}_{i\in I}$, where $B_i=A_i\times {i}$. Notice that $B_i$ is a family of mutually disjoint set. Define $Y=\bigcup _{i\in I}B_i$ and consider the surjection $g:Y\rightarrow I$ where $g(y)=i$ if $y\in B_i$.By assumption, $g$ has a right inverse $f:I\rightarrow Y$ so that $g(f(i))=i$.
